# Run-away Volterra operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, operator-theory, integral-operators

For a continuous function $k:[0,1]^2\to \mathbb{R}$, let $A$ be the generalized Volterra integral operator on $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ defined by
$$
A(f)(t)\triangleq \int_0^t k(s,t)f(s) ds, \quad t \in [0,1].
$$
Given a finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ does there always exist a $k$ as above such that $A$ is injective and for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a Borel subset $B\subseteq C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ such that

- for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $B \cap A^n(B)= \emptyset$,
- $\mu(C([0,1],\mathbb{R})\setminus B)<\epsilon$?

Comment: You probably mean "arbitrarily large measure" (as in arbitrarily close to $\mu(C)$), or else $B=\emptyset$ works.

Comment: Though this won't work either if we take $\mu$ as an $A$ invariant measure.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I edited the condition so that it is indeed arbitrarily small.  Also, true so suppose we ensure that $\mu$ is not $A$ invariant.  If need be, let us assume that $\mu$ is given and that we may choose $k$ (so A).

Comment: @FabianWirth I added details rigorously described what I'm looking for.  So $B$ would be a non-example (unless $\mu=\delta_{f}$ which it need not be in general).

Comment: I fixe dit for them.